# chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension, расширения, вкладки

Консоль выдает такую ошибку, как исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Скрипты

---

backgroundScript

`chrome.storage.local.set({tabs: chrome.tabs});`

---

contentScript

```
chrome.storage.local.get("tabs", function(notTabs) {
    chrome.tabs = notTabs.tabs

    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
        if(changeInfo.url != null) {
            alert(changeInfo.url);
        }
    })
});
chrome.storage.local.remove("tabs")
```

---

Если надо manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "name",
    "version": "1.0",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup/popup.html",
        "default_title": " "
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "tabs",
        "storage"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["https://*/*"],
            "js": ["content_scripts/jquery.min.js", "content_scripts/script.js"],
            "run_at": "document_idle"
        }
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background/background.js"]
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "icon.png",
        "32": "icon.png",
        "48": "icon.png",
        "64": "icon.png",
        "128": "icon.png"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

API `chrome.tabs` не доступен для выполнения на стороне content-script. 

Список доступных для контент скрипта api:

- i18n
- storage
- runtime:

  - connect
  - getManifest
  - getURL
  - id
  - onConnect
  - onMessage
  - sendMessage

Вы можете работать с `.tabs` на стороне background-скрипта.

Comment: Тогда как реализовать так, чтобы контент-скрипт работал только на определенной странице.

Comment: @Василий укажите необходимую страницу (URL pattern)  в `"matches"` в манифест-файле.